# update mongo 2.4 to 2.6

Tags: linux, mongodb, updates

I want to upgrade my mongodb to 3.2, but when I try to upgrade to 2.6 I already get error

What I do:

- I have a test VM with restored dump database from production sever.
- I download mongodb 2.6 and extracted.
- I run mongo from `/tmp/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.11/bin/mongo` 
  In console mongodb run
  `use admin
  db.upgradeCheckAllDBs()`

In there are no problem(I think), I get message from mongo:

```
Everything is ready for the upgrade!
true
```

- when I exit from mongo and run again `/tmp/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.11/bin/mongo` and run command:
  `res = db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({authSchemaUpgrade: 1 });
  print(tojson(res));`

but I got error:

```
res = db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({authSchemaUpgrade: 1 });
 {
       "ok" : 0,
       "errmsg" : "no such cmd: authSchemaUpgrade",
       "bad cmd" : {
        "authSchemaUpgrade" : 1
    }
}
 print(tojson(res));
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "no such cmd: authSchemaUpgrade",
    "bad cmd" : {
        "authSchemaUpgrade" : 1
    }
}
```

And no different what database I use. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve this problem you need to do one thing:
after you do this:

> - I run mongo from /tmp/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.11/bin/mongo In console mongodb run use admin
>     db.upgradeCheckAllDBs()

You should to stop **mongod** previous version and then run **mongod** of version 2.6.
After this you can do **authSchemaUpgrade**